# How do I do a Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How do I make a join of the id_curso of these two tables:

- In this table id_curso is a FOREIGN KEY from the second table
  [image: table1];
- Second Table has id_curso has is Primary_key
  [image: table2]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think a simple google search for "SQL join" gives you a ton of examples. What have you tried?

Comment: Have a look at this image to get a visual of what each type of join does. The answers here are useless unless they explain the difference in the join types. http://i.imgur.com/hhRDO4d.png

Answer (score 1):

For join two table with foreign key related in sample you provided .. inner join

return the subset for row with value common  in each of the two table  .. in this case with the same id_curso and this value must be present in each table .

If you need a simple inner join

```
 select a.*, b.* 
 from table1 as a
 inner join table2 as b on a. id_curso = b.id_curso ;
```

You can see a visual rapresenation an this link provided by @MichaelZ
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHXbB.jpg

Comment: Please take the time to inform us what an inner join is and why you chose it as an example.

Comment: @MichaelZ.  i provided a brief description of the inner join   meaning .. you can find more here http://www.sql-join.com

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I only asked to add this because the OP is  clearly new at this. You might want to add this image or a similar one to your post. http://i.imgur.com/hhRDO4d.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I hope I didn't make any mistakes in here (using `left join`):

```
SELECT * FROM `first_table` LEFT JOIN `second_table` ON (first_table.id_Curso = second_table.id_Curso)
```

Comment: Please take the time to inform us what a left join is and why you chose it as an example.

Comment: I'm used to left joins too :) they're very useful.

Comment: Why "used to"? Why not anymore? :|

Comment: "Used to something" is just a way to say that you are very familiar with something. We're not saying we don't use it anymore. We're saying we use it quite often...so often that we are very familiar with it. A left join is one of the most important joins there are.

Comment: I see. I have learned that "used to" means something did earlier and but today not anymore. :)

Comment: Yes, that is another context to the word. As in "I used to take this route to work" meaning I don't anymore. I could also say "I'm used to taking this route" meaning I take it so often that I'm familiar with it. That's English for you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a join statements it depends upon your scenerio

```
 SELECT a.*, b.* 
 FROM TABLE1 as a
 JOIN TABLE2 as b on a.id_curso = b.id_curso ;

 SELECT a.*, b.* 
 FROM TABLE1 as a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 as b on a.id_curso = b.id_curso ;

 SELECT a.*, b.* 
 FROM TABLE1 as a
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 as b on a.id_curso = b.id_curso ;
```

Comment: This user is clearly new to SQL so these three queries won't make much sense. Can you explain the differences in what they return?